# Rails Joins query not responding like SQL Join query

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, join

I have two tables, package and time_slot and i want to join and return some values

in my package.rb

```
class Package < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :company_id, :time_slot_id, :location_id, :service_id, :day_id, :resource_quantity, :package_category_id, :time_slot, :is_booked
    belongs_to :time_slot
end
```

in my time_slot.rb

```
class TimeSlot < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :start_time, :end_time
    has_many :package
end
```

in my sql query when i do run this query, it works perfectly

```
SELECT packages.id, time_slots.start_time, time_slots.end_time FROM packages INNER JOIN time_slots ON packages.time_slot_id = time_slots.id;
```

this is the result 
[image]

But when i run the same query in Rails c

```
Package.joins("LEFT JOIN time_slots ON packages.time_slot_id = time_slots.id").select("packages.id, time_slots.start_time, time_slots.end_time")
```

it only returns this

```
 #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Package id: 1>, #<Package id: 2>, #<Package id: 3>]>
```

Any one knows why? Any help appreciated

Comment: have no idea about the issue. just a sidenote - if you need to have INNER JOIN like you do in your sql query, just use - joins(:time_slots)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't "return" that. That's the `to_s` representation of what it does return.

The Package model doesn't have a start_time or end_time attribute, so the console doesn't show the selected values when inspecting the relation.

But each of those objects *will* return those values when called. Run your query again and try adding:

```
.first.start_time
```

Or

```
.map(&:attributes)
```

Comment: yah i read up on some documentation and realised this yday. A total waste of my 2hrs trying to find out whts wrong. Thanks anywys @pavling

Comment: Reading the documentation Is never a waste :-)